# How to use physionet wfdb commands in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command, signals

I have a C# project in which I have to read ecg signal files from dat files downloaded from the ecg signal database found on physionet's website. My question is: How can I use wfdb commands in Visual Studio (v. 10). I've read about wrappers and they provide wfdb libraries to do the work instead of me, but it's not what I need. I'd like to find a way to somehow use the commands like in an XServer xterm terminal. More specifically I only need the rsdamp and the rdann commands, because I want to reed signal and annotation files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 http://wfdbcsharpwrapper.codeplex.com/
```

To answer my own question, this is a wfdb c# wrapper library.